# python read_csv with sep parameters is giving all in one column or says expected 2 fileds in line 6 but saw 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to read a *.inp file into a data frame.

the file looks like this

```
B*** BASE  321 Emit 200.000

/mrpo

:B311

:200.

Emit,   200.000

CG,    1,UFNQ,    123.56

CG,    2,UFNQ,    143.76

CG,    33,UFNQ,   123.56

CG,    223,UFNQ,  143.76

B*** qwqwndqq is iellai ai  200.000  67

B*** qwqwndqq is iellai ai  5050.000 63

/mrpo

B*** END 321 Emit 200.000

/EOF
```

I want read it as dataframe and access and change the second number in all rows ( expect in first 5 and last 3 lines ) and rewrite a new *.inp file

This is the code I am using

```
df=pandas.read_csv(file_name, sep =',',header = None, engine ='python')
```

output:Expected 1 fields in line 7 saw 2

```
df=pandas.read_csv(file_name, sep ='s',header = None, engine ='python')
```

output:all in one column

```
df=pandas.read_csv(file_name, sep ='delimiter',header = None, engine ='python')
```

output:all in one column

I want new file like this

```
B*** BASE  321 Emit 200.000

/mrpo

:B311

:200.

Emit,   200.000

CG,    10001,UFNQ,    123.56

CG,    10002,UFNQ,    143.76

CG,    10033,UFNQ,   123.56

CG,    10223,UFNQ,  143.76

B*** qwqwndqq is iellai ai  200.000  67

B*** qwqwndqq is iellai ai  5050.000 63

/mrpo

B*** END 321 Emit 200.000

/EOF
```

please suggest if there is any other way in python

Comment: Text file is like this:

Comment: Are there  any column headers? What is the output supposed to look like? you should probably use header parameter to start at the right row

Comment: there are no column headers........out file dataframe should be like I can access df.iloc[5:8,2] = df.iloc[5:8,2] + 10000                                                                                                        and save as new *.inp by df.to_csv(path_out, header= None, index = None, sep=',',mode ='w',engine = 'python').                                                                           and the output file should look like posted bottom in question

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to a dataframe? Your file doesn't have the same number of elements in each row, and therefore it won't work well in a tabular format like a dataframe. If all you want to do is change those numbers in the middle rows, why don't you just treat this as text and use some regex to change whatever you need?

Comment: should table be used...can you an  example

Answer (score 0):

I would use csv reader for this. This is roughly how I'd do it, but there could be some adjustments that need to be made to the indexing..

```
import csv

filename = 'input.csv'
tempfile = 'output.csv'

with open(filename, 'rb') as csvFile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if (i >= 4) and (i<row_count-3):
            row[1] = 10000 + row[1]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I get an error that with open(filenae,'rb') as csvFile, tempfile:      AttributeError:-____enter____